# Is it impossible to have ListvVew in Custom Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview, android-dialog

If the `showChatList()` function is not being called in the code, and the dialog is displayed normally.

When the `listView` is called via `showChatList()` function, it does not work.

To the original custom dialog

Is it impossible to bring up the listView?

```
public void callFunction() {

    final Dialog dlg = new Dialog(context);

    dlg.setContentView(R.layout.room_list);

    dlg.show();

    final Button okButton = (Button) dlg.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    final Button backbtn = (Button) dlg.findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

    **final ListView chat_list = (ListView) dlg.findViewById(R.di.chat_list);**

    - or

    **chat_list = dlg.findViewById(R.id.chat_list);**

    backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dlg.dismiss();
        }
    });

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dlg.dismiss();
        }
    });

    showChatList();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to describe better your intent in the code, with the info provided is hard to provide a proper answer

Comment: If the `ListView` is indeed in the `Dialog`'s `room_list` layout, then you need to find `chat_list` the same way you are the two `Button`s in `callFunction()`, from the `Dialog`; e.g., `chat_list = dlg.findViewById(R.id.chat_list_or_whatever_the_id_is)`.

Comment: @MikeM. 
thx for the answer. I trying to your suggest code, but I got same problem.

Comment: We'd need to see your updated code. Please [edit] your question to update with what you have now.

Comment: @MikeM.
I tried using the code you suggested to two examples, but it didn't work.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? That wasn't really clear in the original question either. Is it crashing? Is the `ListView` just not showing in the `Dialog`? Something else?

Comment: @MikeM.
The app is stopped when the Dialog is called up.
If I don't use showChatList() function, it works normally.

Comment: Oh, OK. I read your question as meaning that the `ListView` just wasn't visible in the `Dialog`. If it's crashing, there will be a stack trace in your logcat that will point out the exact cause. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174) to see where you can find that stack trace, and what it will look like. Please add the whole thing to your question, as text, when you find it.

Comment: @MikeM.
I Added image link on post.

Comment: OK, you didn't mention that you're calling this code from another `Activity`. The problem is that your `RoomList` class should not extend `AppCompatActivity`, as it is not being used as an `Activity`. It's just a helper class. If you really want to keep all of this stuff in that separate class, then you need remove the `extends AppCompatActivity` from the class declaration, and use your `private Context context;` field for anything that requires a `Context`; e.g., `new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, ...)`. (Btw, please post all text as text, rather than as screenshots.)

Comment: @MikeM.
OMG!! Thank you so much for your hard work for me.
Now it works really fine :D

Comment: No problem. In the future, please provide a little more detail in your questions – e.g., describe exactly how it's not working, how the given code is called, etc. – and if it's crashing, please post the stack trace at the start. It'll make it much easier for us to get you a solution. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter depends on firebase.
It will wait until it gets data,
then I believe you need to call

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

```
    adapter.add();
```

Comment: thx for the answer.
I trying to your suggest code, but I got same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with views like dialogs, it is important to load all the views needed in the dialog before calling `dialog.show()`.
Alternatively, I'll suggest the use of [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragmen%5D/app/DialogFragment) with this example: https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-dialog-fragment-in-android.
`DialogFragment`s allow you to manage your dialogs just like any other fragment.

Let me know which one you're able to use.